# push item to same nested child in array deep

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I can't be able to figure out how to push items to same nested array like :

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello'];
 // It should be now look like this: 
const output = {name: 'foo', children: [
      {name: 'bar', children: [
          {name: 'buz', children: [
              {name: 'hello', children: []}
          ]}
      ]}
  ]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive function:

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello'];
const f = (arr) => ({name: arr.shift(), children: arr.length ? [f(arr)] : []});
const output = f(arr);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Though @klugjo answer using reduce method is good, but I accepted this answer as this is what I've tried (and failed) and it is understandable by beginner like me what's happening. `Array.reduce` always look alien to me. P.S. : It would be more better if you write the answer without any array methods like replacing `arr.shift()` with increment or something.

Comment: I'm personally in favor of the `reduceRight()` approach by @HassanImam

Answer (score 4):

Using `reduce`:

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello'];

const result = arr.reverse().reduce((acc, val) => ({name: val, children: [acc]}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduceRight` to create the output.

```js
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello'],
    result = arr.reduceRight((r, name) => ({name, children: (!Object.keys(r).length ? [] : [r])}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `recursive` function

```js
function nested (arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1)
    return { name: arr.shift(), children: [] };
  else if (arr.length > 1) 
    return { name: arr.shift(), children: [nested(arr)] };
}

var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello']
console.log(nested(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have an idea on how `Array.reduce()` method work, so posted another answer without recursive approach. I think it would be better for large tree structure.
The basic idea is that simply reverse the input array and then wrap the innermost object into another and so on.

```
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz', 'hello'];
function nest(arr) {
    arr = arr.reverse();
    let out = [];
    arr.forEach(it => {
        if(out.length === 0) out = {name: it, children: []}
        else {
            out = {name: it, children: [out]}
        }
    });
    return out;
}
```